# Cannot mock in Jest with ES modules

Tags: jestjs, mocking

I'm trying to reproduce the example given in [Jest documentation about mocking module](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#mocking-modules). The code is the following one.

**users.js**

```
import axios from 'axios'

class Users {
  static all () {
    return axios.get('/users.json').then(resp => resp.data)
  }
}

export default Users
```

**test.js**

```
import axios from 'axios'
import Users from './users'
import { jest } from '@jest/globals'
jest.mock('axios')

test('should fetch users', () => {
  const users = [ { name: 'Bob' } ]
  const resp = { data: users }
  axios.get.mockResolvedValue(resp)

  // or you could use the following depending on your use case:
  // axios.get.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(resp))

  return Users.all().then(data => expect(data).toEqual(users))
})
```

The code from **test.js** is a little bit different from the documentation. I had to add `import { jest } from '@jest/globals'` because of [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/9430#issuecomment-616232029)

**package.json**

```
{
  ...
  "type": "module",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=14.17.6"
  },
  "config": {
    "nuxt": {
      "host": "0.0.0.0",
      "port": "8081"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon --insecure-http-parser --inspect server/index.js --watch server",
    "test-server": "cross-env CYPRESS_MODE=true THIRD_PARTY_ROUTES_ENABLED=false npm run start",
    "ci-test-server": "npm run test-server & wait-on http://localhost:8081/fr-FR",
    "build-for-cypress": "cross-env NUXT_ENV_CYPRESS_MODE=true npm run build",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node --insecure-http-parser server/index.js",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "precommit": "npm run lint",
    "phrase": "node scripts/phraseapp/phraseapp.js",
    "cypress:open-mocked": "cypress open --env env=mock",
    "cypress:run-mocked": "cypress run --env env=mock",
    "cypress:open-unmocked": "cypress open --env=real,\"TAGS=not @mockOnly\"",
    "cypress:run-unmocked": "cypress run --env=real,\"TAGS=not @mockOnly\"",
    "ci-test": "cross-env TEST_MODE=true jest tests --runInBand  --coverage",
    "front-unit-tests": "cross-env jest tests/client/unit",
    "back-tests": "cross-env TEST_MODE=true jest tests/server --runInBand"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@cospired/i18n-iso-languages": "^3.1.0",
    "@jest/globals": "^27.2.5",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.6",
    "@nuxtjs/dotenv": "^1.4.1",
    "@nuxtjs/i18n": "^7.0.3",
    "@nuxtjs/proxy": "^2.1.0",
    "@nuxtjs/style-resources": "^1.2.1",
    "@nuxtjs/toast": "^3.3.1",
    "@sport-activities/nuxt-di": "^0.1.2",
    "@vtmn/css": "^0.22.1",
    "@vtmn/icons": "^0.4.0",
    "abort-controller": "^3.0.0",
    "agentkeepalive": "^4.1.4",
    "atob": "^2.1.2",
    "axios": "^0.22.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cacheable-lookup": "^6.0.1",
    "connect-redis": "^6.0.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "cookie-universal-nuxt": "^2.1.5",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "csurf": "^1.11.0",
    "dd-trace": "^1.4.1",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-session": "^1.17.2",
    "express-validator": "^6.12.2",
    "google-libphonenumber": "^3.2.24",
    "helmet": "^4.6.0",
    "ioredis": "^4.27.9",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "luxon": "^2.0.2",
    "memory-cache": "^0.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "nock": "^13.1.3",
    "node-cron": "^3.0.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.8",
    "nuxt-lazy-load": "^1.2.7",
    "nuxt-purgecss": "^1.0.0",
    "oauth": "^0.9.15",
    "p-limit": "^3.1.0",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-oauth2": "^1.6.1",
    "redlock": "^4.2.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "validator": "^13.6.0",
    "vue-server-renderer": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-toasted": "^1.1.28",
    "wait-on": "^6.0.0",
    "winston": "^3.3.3",
    "world-countries": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.5",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.15.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.6",
    "@jest/types": "^27.2.4",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.2",
    "@vue/test-utils": "1.2.2",
    "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.20.0",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "css-loader": "^5.2.7",
    "cypress": "8.5.0",
    "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.2.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^16.0.3",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.24.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^5.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.18.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "ioredis-mock": "^5.6.0",
    "jest": "^27.2.4",
    "less": "^4.1.1",
    "less-loader": "^7.2.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.13",
    "supertest": "^6.1.6",
    "vue-i18n": "8.26.5",
    "vue-jest": "^3.0.7",
    "vue-svg-loader": "^0.16.0"
  },
  "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
    "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": false,
    "step_definitions": "tests/client/e2e/integration/steps",
    "cucumberJson": {
      "generate": true,
      "outputFolder": "tests/client/e2e/integration/cucumber-json",
      "filePrefix": "",
      "fileSuffix": ".cucumber"
    }
  }
}
```

**jest.config.js**

```
export default {
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$': '<rootDir>/tests/client/unit/__mocks__/fileMock.js',
    '\\.(css|less)$': '<rootDir>/tests/client/unit/__mocks__/styleMock.js',
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/$1'
  },
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    'js',
    'json',
    'vue',
    'svg'
  ],
  transform: {},
  testMatch: [
    '**/?(*.)+(test).[jt]s?(x)',
    '**/tests/routes/**/*.spec.js'
  ],
  testEnvironment : 'jsdom',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: [
    './tests/jest-setup/jest.setup.ioredis-mock.js',
    './tests/jest-setup/jest.setup.timers.js',
    './tests/jest-setup/jest.setup.envvar.js',
    './tests/jest-setup/jest.setup.nock.js',
    './tests/jest-setup/jest.setup.redis-cache.js'
  ]
}
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }]
  ]
}
```

When executing the test, I'm getting this as a result:

```
axios.get.mockResolvedValue is not a function
TypeError: axios.get.mockResolvedValue is not a function
```

Looks like the mock won't work. What have I missed to make it work?